# Google Analytics Standard E Commerce data is not recorded from Hit Builder

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, measurement-protocol

We are using Measurement Protocol to log our transaction data to Google Analytics Standard E Commerce.

I have enabled the E-Commerce setting for the view, and sent a sample data through Hit Builder.

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/

[image]

[image]

It is been more than 2 hours, but still i cant find the data recorded under E Commerce report.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any filter in the view? For example for the host name or page path?

Comment: @MichelePisani it took nearly 12-15 hours for the first data to be recorded in the ECommerce report. Now i can see my data :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data pushed through Hit Builder is now recorded in my Google Analytics ECommerce report. It took nearly 12-15hours for my first data to be reflected. Once the first data is recorded, the other upcoming data are reflected within 1-2 minutes. Need to be more patient for your first data to be recorded. :)

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency

[image]